# Extracting CDS sequences in Biopython

Tags: sequences, biopython

Good day everyone,

I'm starting to program in Biopython and I'm wondering how to extract the gene sequences and protein identifiers from a genome GenBank file (*.gb) having the coordinates of all features.

My idea is to create a text file containing the protein identifiers, the coordinates of the genes and the gene sequences.

If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate them.

I tried this so far:

```
for seq_record in seq_record.features: 
    if seq_record.type == 'CDS':
       x=seq_record.qualifiers['protein_id']
       i=seq_record.location._start.position
       f=seq_record.location._end.position
       sq = seq_record.seq
       FEAT_LIST.append('START END STRAND ID')
       FEAT_LIST.append(str(((i, f), s, x, sq)))
       print(FEAT_LIST)
```

However, I get this error: sq = seq_record.seq AttributeError: 'SeqFeature' object has no attribute 'seq'

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What did you tried? Did you look in the [Biopython](www.biopython.org) tutorial/wiki?
The short answer is make a parser if there isn't any that does what you want.

Answer (score 5):

FeatureLocation has a nice `extract` method, that takes the parent sequence and gives you a new SeqRecord object. Over that object you can use the usual `.seq` to get the sequence:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for rec in SeqIO.parse("sequence.gb", "genbank"):
    if rec.features:
        for feature in rec.features:
            if feature.type == "CDS":
                print feature.location
                print feature.qualifiers["protein_id"]
                print feature.location.extract(rec).seq
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look into Biopython documentation for `SeqIO` and `SeqRecord` objects, such as `parse` and `read`. The `genbank` format is implemented in the parser so you should not have any problems to read the file. Indeed, you only have to specify `genbank` as a parameter.

[Here](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord) you even have an example for reading genbank files.

**Edit**: So I gather you have a problem when iterating through the records. The problem I see is that there is a confusion between `SeqRecord` objects and `SeqFeature` objects. You cannot do:

```
for seq_record in seq_record.features:
```

because then `seq_record` is a `SeqFeature` object, **NOT** a `SeqRecord` one. When you first parse a GenBank file, you get to iterate through `SeqRecord` objects:

```
for record in SeqIO.parse('my_file.gbk','genbank'):
    print "Record %s has %i features and sequence: %s" % (record.id, len(record.features), record.seq)
```

Each `SeqRecord` object has a `seq` attribute and a list of `SeqFeature` objects in the `features` attribute. If you want to do something with the features, you need to iterate through them for each record.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

However, my issue appears when I try to run this code: 

`for seq_record in seq_record.features:`
`        if seq_record.type == 'CDS':`
`            x=seq_record.qualifiers['protein_id']`
`            i=seq_record.location._start.position`
`            f=seq_record.location._end.position`
`       sq = seq_record.seq`
`      FEAT_LIST.append('START END STRAND ID')`
`            FEAT_LIST.append(str(((i, f), s, x, sq)))`

`print(FEAT_LIST)`

I get this error:     sq = seq_record.seq
AttributeError: 'SeqFeature' object has no attribute 'seq'

Comment: I edited my answer to try to be more explanatory. I also think that the code you posted should be made visible in your question. Posted an edit on that.

Answer (score 0):

The seqfeature object has an [extract method](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature-class.html#extract) that saves you the trouble of digging into the FeatureLocation. It returns a new sequence.

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_protein
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature, FeatureLocation
seq = Seq("MKQHKAMIVALIVICITAVVAAL", generic_protein)
f = SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(8, 15), type="domain")
f.extract(seq)
# returns: Seq('VALIVIC', ProteinAlphabet())
```